# AngularJS nested modal templates

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a spa developed with AngularJS (routing with ngroute). Every template have the menu, in the menu there is a back button. I want to return to the previous view with he's state (information, scroll in the page etc). If I code every button in the menu to open the next template in modal that have dimension of full screen, and the back button just close the current modal. This method can do a memory leak?

This case is an hybrid application running in the tablet, the back button is in the menu of application not that of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `$window.history.back();`
Why don't you create a template for the menu and include it into your views by using ng-include?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, my concern is to return to the previous view with his state, history.back() can do that?

Comment: this case is an hybrid application runing in the tablet, the back button is in the menu of application not that of the browser